# When should ashrai-uvo lzion be said

Tags: tefilla, shacharis-morning-prayer, musaf, nusach-ashkenaz

Most nusach sefard has ashrai-uvo lzion while doing g'lila before the sefer torah is returned to the ark, which works out 'quicker'. What is correct nusach ashkenaz. Is it different on rosh chodesh or chol hamoed where the kaddish afterwards also applies to mussaph.

Comment: What is "correct nusach ashkenaz"?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're incorrect that "[m]ost nusach sefard has ashrai-uvo lzion while doing g'lila". In my experience, at least, most *nusach-S'farad* synagogues say it *after g'lila* — or at least finish it after *g'lila*. This is especially true on days *tachanun* is said.

Anyway, in my experience, *nusach Ashk'naz* generally completes *g'lila* and, if applicable, "*Y'hi ratzon*", puts away the *Tora* and then says "*Ashre*" etc. with no *kadish* intervening. Then comes *kadish* and then, if applicable, *musaf*.